# [MS Access]Set Combobox on OpenForm based on what record is selected in datasheet form

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2013

So here is the datasheet form

[image]

In the combo box I set value based on Employee ID

[image]

As of now I looked at .CurrentRecord but that returns the row number not the ID.
I can succesfully pass the .CurrentRecord Value to the form and set that as the ComboBox problem is the number of row is not necessarily equal to the Employee ID

What I want is the User to be able to select a record on the sheet that is an employee and when the User presses the Trainings button it shows the second form with combo box set to that employees ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recording value so it's not lost when button is clicked with timer event, timing is set to 500

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    value = Me.EID.value
End Sub
```

I passed the value using DoCmd.OpenForm last argument.

```
Private Sub trainings_Click()
    On Error GoTo trainings_Click_Err

    ' _AXL:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
    ' <UserInterfaceMacro For="show_trainings" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2009/11/application"><Statements><Action Name="OpenForm"><Argument Name="FormName">Employee
    ' _AXL:Trainings</Argument><Argument Name="WhereCondition">="[ATTUID]="  &amp;"'" &amp;[ATTUID] &amp; "'"</Argument></Action></Statements></UserInterfaceMacro>
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Add Training", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal, value


trainings_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

trainings_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume trainings_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

and at last I read the Argument and set the Combo box value and for the dependent listboxes I called requery

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
        Me.cboEmp = Me.OpenArgs
        Me.List14.Requery
        Me.List18.Requery
    End If
End Sub
```